# How to view details of users having same names in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a user model having details like email-id, name, address, dob etc. I want to design my app in such a way that all the distinct names are displayed and when you click at show button beside that name, all the details of users having that particular name will be displayed. I am new to rails so I need some suggestion.

Here is my controller code and view code. The unique names are appearing but when I click at the show link beside the name nothing appears.

tasks_controller.rb

```
    class TasksController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @names = User.distinct.pluck(:name)
      end
      def show
        @users = User.where(name: params[:name])
      end
    end
```

index.html.erb

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @names.each do |n| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= n %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', task_path(n) %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %> 
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

show.html.erb

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Email-id</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @users.each do |u| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= u.email%></td>
          <td><%= u.dob%></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %> 
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In index method you'll fetch all the uniq names

```
def index
  @names = User.distinct.pluck(:name)
end
```

now show method, you'll pass name as a parameter

```
def show
  @users = User.where(name: params[:name])
end
```

loop through all the records on show page to see all the records of users having same name and on the index page loop through all the names and add a button or an anchor to open the show page.

Comment: Thanks for the help! There is no issue in displaying the distinct names but when I click on the show link beside the name, nothing appears. Please check my syntax. Here is index view:                                                                                
 <% @names.each do |t| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= t %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', task_path(t) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

Comment: And here is my show view:    <% @users.each do |u| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= u.email%></td>
      <td><%= u.dob%></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

Comment: please update the code in the question itself and add the controller code as well. 
in show method try replacing params[:name] with params[:id]